# How to maintain relative symbolic links during copy?

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, xcopy

I have a directory structure with a bunch of relative symbolic links. Example:

e:\test
e:\test\foo\a --> "..\bar"
e:\test\bar\b --> "..\foo"

Is there a way to copy the entirety of the directory from parent on down to an arbitrary location (backup drive...), and maintain the symlink's relativity? In the above example, I want "a" to continue to point to "up one level, then down to \bar".

I can get xcopy to deep-copy the contents of each symlink, but that wastes too much space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this PowerShell script, tested on Windows 10:

```
param ([string]$Source, [string]$Dest)
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Function ReplaceString($text, $original, $replacement) {
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings]::Replace($text, $original, $replacement, 1, -1, 'Text')
}
$Source = (Resolve-Path $Source).Path
$Dest = (Resolve-Path $Dest).Path
Function CopySubdir($subdirPath) {
    gci $subdirPath -Force | % {
        If (-not $_.PSIsContainer) {
            Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
        } ElseIf ($_.LinkType -ne 'SymbolicLink') {
            $newFolderPath = (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
            mkdir $newFolderPath
            CopySubdir $_.FullName
        }
    }
}
CopySubdir $Source
gci $Source -Recurse -Force | ? {$_.LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'} | % {
    $newPath = (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
    Push-Location $_.Parent.FullName
    $newTarget = (ReplaceString (Resolve-Path $_.Target).Path $Source $Dest)
    Pop-Location
    New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target $newTarget
}
```

Save it as a `.ps1` file and follow the Enabling Scripts instructions in [the PowerShell tag wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/powershell/info). You can then run the script from a PowerShell prompt like this:

```
.\symcopy.ps1 -Source 'C:\my\source' -Dest 'D:\dest'
```

It works with relative paths as well, like `.\source`.

To run from a normal command prompt:

```
powershell -command ".\symcopy.ps1 -Source 'C:\my\source' -Dest 'D:\dest'"
```

The destination should be an empty folder that will receive the same contents as the source folder. All files and folders will be copied as usual, but all symlinks will be examined and adjusted and copied later, once everything else is in place.

Some caveats: Since standard users cannot create symlinks under normal conditions, this script must be run as administrator. Some `ResourceExists` errors may be thrown in the last stage; these are not fatal and can be ignored.

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for copying symbolic links - instead began copying link's destination files.  Thank you for your hard work, though.

Comment: @AveryFreeman It's been a while, but it looks like this script does not specially handle file symbolic links, only directory symbolic links. Also, it is not aware of directory junctions. Might one of those be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was for all symbolic links - would be nice to have one that copies symlinks for files, too

Answer (score 1):

I simply improved on BenN's answer so that it works with file symbolic links as well:

```
param ([string]$Source, [string]$Dest)

$Source = (Resolve-Path $Source).Path
$Dest = (Resolve-Path $Dest).Path

Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Function ReplaceString($text, $original, $replacement) {
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings]::Replace($text, $original, $replacement, 1, -1, 'Text')
}
Function CopySubdir($subdirPath) {
    dir $subdirPath -Force | % {
        If ($_.LinkType -ne 'SymbolicLink') {
            If (-not $_.PSIsContainer) {
                Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
            } Else {
                $newFolderPath = (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
                mkdir $newFolderPath
                CopySubdir $_.FullName
            }
        }
    }
}
CopySubdir $Source
dir $Source -Recurse -Force | ? {$_.LinkType -eq 'SymbolicLink'} | % {
    $newPath = (ReplaceString $_.FullName $Source $Dest)
    Push-Location $_.Parent.FullName
    $newTarget = (ReplaceString (Resolve-Path $_.Target).Path $Source $Dest)
    Pop-Location
    New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType SymbolicLink -Target $newTarget
}
```